# Swap character groups in String in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to swap character groups in a String.
For example:

```
swap("aabbcdefg","aa","bb")  = bbaacdefg

swap("aabbcdefg","aa","efg") = efgbbcdaa
```

I did something like this:

```
static String swap(String val, String sub1, String sub2)
    {

        String temp="tt";
        val= val.replace(sub1,temp);
        val= val.replace(sub2,sub1);       
        val= val.replace(temp,sub2);
        return val;
    }
```

Can I do it in more efficient way?

Comment: Your approach will not work if the string contains element equal to your *temp*.

Comment: What you mean with *efficient*? Less memory? Better performance? Less source code?

Comment: Yeah better performance and less code

Comment: If possible using any built in method or something?

Comment: what if swap("aaabbcdefg","aa","bb")? then bbaaacdefg is correct or abbaacdefg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code would break if trying to handle `tt`.

This code splits by `sub1`, loops through and replaces `sub2` with `sub1` and joins with `sub2`.

```
static String swap(String val, String sub1, String sub2)
    {
        String[] items = val.split(sub1);
        for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++) 
        { 
            items[i] = items[i].replace(sub2, sub1);
        }
        return String.join(sub2, items);
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of `tt` as a temporary variable .